# How to draw a zoomed bitmap on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I want to create a tile editor in WPF. It should display a tile (a bitmap with a maximum dimension 64x64 pixels) as a grid of squares about 2x2 pixels each. If the tile is smaller, like 32x32, the squares should become bigger, like 4x4, so it takes the same space on the canvas.

The first straight forward approach would be to create a rectangle for each pixel and then color them with the color of the pixels of the original image. But this way I would create a huge amount (4096) rectangles which I think is not very effective. If the user clicks of one of these rectangles, change it's color and the corresponding color in the original bitmap

Another approach would be, to create an image of 3*64 x 3*64 pixels (the 2x2 pixels plus 1 pixel between them) and draw on that bitmap. But then I have to refresh the whole image when altering one pixel.

In older not object-oriented times it would be simple. Iterate through all the pixels of the original image in two x/y loops and draw each pixel like this:

```
zoomfactor = 2;
for (y=0; y<ymax, y++)
{
    for (x=0; x<xmax; x++)
    {
        Rectangle (x0 + (zoomfactor+1)*x,  // x coordinate
                   y0 + (zoomfactor+1)*y,  // y coordinate
                   zoomfactor,             // x size
                   zoomfactor,             // y size
                   GetPixel(bitmap, x, y); // color
    }
}
```

If the user clicks into the area, you only redraw the affected pixel like above and draw the new pixel also into the original bitmap.

So what do you think is an effective way to show and edit a zoomed bitmap? Or maybe WPS is not so good at all for this kind of application. If the tile editor is ready, I will also edit a whole tile map, so I will get the same issue there. Display a big number of rectangles (the tiles) on a control and edit them. Maybe SDL is the better approach. Or can I use both? WPF for all that GUI stuff and an SDL "canvas" for the tiles, tilemaps and tilesets.

Thanks
Thorsten

Comment: Are you aware that you could simply display an Image element in a Panel that scales its child elements (e.g. a Grid) and set BitmapScalingMode to NearestNeighbor to show precisely scaled pixels? Use a WriteableBitmap as the Source of the Image element.

Comment: Yes, I know about scaling image, but I would like a small grid around the individual pixels. What is new for me is WriteableBitmap. I will look into it. Maybe that is the solution. Create a scaled copy of the original image including the grid and paint into it like described in the question.